# Chrome issue with text-shadow color on transformed paragraphs

Tags: google-chrome, colors, css-transforms, css

For whatever reason, when I apply a CSS transform to a paragraph that already has a text-shadow applied, the color of the text-shadow becomes the color of the paragraph, regardless of the color specified for text-shadow in my css.  This issue only seems to happen on Chrome, it works fine in firefox.  The example website below should demonstrate this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        p
        {
            text-shadow: 10px 10px #000000;
            color:#FF0000;
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(10deg);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world!  Chrome will work now?</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to apply a rotation to a paragraph and have it render the text-shadow correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question in hopes that it saves someone else time, after some tinkering it seems that adding a blur, either positive or negative, to the text shadow fixed this issue.  Replacing
    `text-shadow: 10px 10px #000000;`
with
    `text-shadow: 10px 10px -1px #000000;`
displays the text shadow at the appropriate color.